# Non-contiguous array as filter criteria for xlfiltervalues

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, criteria

Common problem, I have worked through all answers I've found and finally got it almost working.

I have a list of discount options, let's call them named range F, down 1 column.
User filters out the discounts they don't want to apply.
I need to unfilter, do work, and refilter as the user selected.

I create an array with only visible cells, by loop and union of ranges. This works correctly, but generates a non-contiguous array usually.

When I run this, I don't get an error. However, the entry below the break in the contiguous array is not refiltered.

***Just realised it's the transpose that doesn't like non-contiguous arrays - still need assistance and doubtless others have same issue so leaving as is***

What's the easiest, most painless (it's nearly Friday), way to persuade Criteria1 to include the last elements in my non-contiguous array?

```
Sub Filters()

'Dimension variables
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i, Lim As Integer
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim Op As Variant

Set w = ActiveSheet

'Set Lim as total number of rows in named range "F" (only 1 cell in use but same effect)
Lim = Range("F").Rows.Count

'Data has header row so skip to row 2
i = 2

'Loop through i up to limit
Do While i <= Lim
    'If the row is not hidden by the filters the user chose

    If Range("F")(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        'Check if the range is nothing - if it is, union will not work to itself
        'Union requires non-empty arguments

        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            'Set the Rng to include the current cell from "F"
            Set Rng = Range("F")(i, 1)

        Else
            'If Rng has some value, add the current cell to it by Union
            Set Rng = Application.Union(Rng, Range("F")(i, 1))

        End If

    End If

    'Increment i
    i = i + 1

    Loop

    If w.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).Operator <> False Then Op = w.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).Operator

    'This gives the correct range, but most often non-contiguous
    MsgBox Range("F").Address

    'Remove AutoFilter
    w.AutoFilterMode = False




    'Insert Code Here




    'Put filters back

    'Check for Rng being non-empty (pointless running code if it is)
    If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then
        'If there is an operator then use the array
        If Op Then
            'Found this option useful here - can transpose the array values which generates an array Criteria1 can use
            'Always xlFilterValues as there will always be more than 2 options
            'Also the options are taken from the worksheet live so won't change between times so specifying them precisely as strings is ok
            Range("F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(Rng.Value), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
        Else
            'Just filter the range but leave all options available
            Range("F").AutoFilter Field:=1
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "User filters out the discounts they don't want to apply. I need to unfilter, do work, and refilter as the user selected.". What kind of work? Depending on the nature of the "work", this perhaps could be performed with a PivotTable. (Perhaps utilising the DataModel too, if you've got Excel 2013 or later.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I didn't learn pivot tables when they came out and feel like an old dog  the work is basically inserting rows and page breaks above the filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by using a second counter to count successful entries that should be included as criteria, and writing them to a range in another worksheet. 
Then set the range to be that new (contiguous) range in the new worksheet.

Now works like a charm at last. Only took me all day to find syntax that worked with Criteria, and figure that you can only use xlOr for up to 2 criteria, otherwise it's xlfiltervalues...

Final working code as generic as I can get it to be as helpful as possible:

```
Sub Filters()

'Dimension variables
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i, j, Lim As Integer
Dim w As Worksheet
Dim Op As Variant

Set w = ActiveSheet

'Set Lim as total number of rows in named range "F" (only 1 cell in use but same effect)
Lim = Range("F").Rows.Count

'Data has header row so skip to row 2
i = 2

'Loop through i up to limit
Do While i <= Lim
    'If the row is not hidden by the filters the user chose

    If Range("F")(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        'Check if the range is nothing - if it is, union will not work to itself
        'Union requires non-empty arguments

        If Rng Is Nothing Then
            'Set the Rng to include the current cell from "F"
            Set Rng = Range("F")(i, 1)
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A75").Value = Range("F")(i, 1).Value
            j = j + 1
        Else
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Offset(j, 0).Value = Range("F")(i, 1).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If

    End If

'Increment i
i = i + 1

Loop

'If there's an operator, save it as variable Op (if needed)
If w.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).Operator <> False Then Op = w.AutoFilter.Filters.Item(1).Operator


'Remove AutoFilter
w.AutoFilterMode = False




'Insert Code Here

'Pause between the two halves
MsgBox ""



'Put filters back

'Check for Rng being non-empty (pointless running code if it is)
If Not IsEmpty(Rng) Then
    'If there is an operator then use the range
    If Op Then
        'Found this option useful here - can transpose the array values
        'Always xlFilterValues as there will always be more than 2 options
        'Also the options are taken from the worksheet live so won't change between times so specifying them precisely as strings is ok
        Range("F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A75").Resize(j, 1).Value), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Else
        'Just filter the range but leave all options available
        Range("F").AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If
End If


End Sub
```